# RxJs- Observable - How to fetch data from JSON Object

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a JSON response observable as below.I would like to get data from this observables in two seperate array such as [abc,xyz] and [aa,bb]. Is it possible using rx observables map and switchmap to get two arrays in the same observable.

```
this.data$ = Observable.of({
      "data": [
        {
          "firstname": "abc",
          "lastname": "aa"
        },
         {
          "firstname": "xyz",
          "lastname": "bb"
        }
      ]
    })  .map(res => res.data)
      .switchMap(dataArray => {
        return Observable.from(dataArray);
      })
      .map((arrayResp: any) => {
        return ( arrayResp.firstname);
      }).toArray()
```

Here iam only able to get one array. Is it possible to get two arrays in this method only.

Comment: You are getting only one object, you want to get the array of all the objects ? Is it what you mean ?

Comment: Yes i want to get array of firstname and lastname seperately

Comment: is that worked for you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use the arrays map function :

```js
.pipe(
    map(res => res.data),
    map(a => ({
        firstnames: a.map(_ => _.firstname),
        lastnames: a.map(_ => _.lastname),
    })),
);
```

[Here is a running example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-50128402)

Comment: Can we not do this without the buffercount?

Comment: Sorry, I can't even understand why I ended up with something that complicated for this simple task. I edited my answer and also the stackblitz.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 2):

you have json string so you need to do like this in your `switchMap` method

```
 .switchMap(dataArray => {
        return Observable.from(JSON.parse( dataArray));
      })
```

or you can do like this also

```
this.data$ = Observable.of(JSON.parse(`{
      "data": [
        {
          "firstname": "abc",
          "lastname": "aa"
        },
         {
          "firstname": "xyz",
          "lastname": "bb"
        }
      ]
    }`).subscribe(res=> console.log(res.data));
```